# Implement storage class to store multiple instances of some class

Tags: c++, class

We have a storage class, class `Person` with the following definition:

```
class Person
{
public:
    string m_name;
    string m_address;
    string m_phone_number;
};
```

We wish to have a storage class, `PersonPool`,  that stores all Person's instances.

**Class requirements:**

1. Should contain all Person's instances.
2. Should provide method to add Person to the pool.
3. Should provide **fast** access method to remove a person **by address**
4. Should provide **fast non-const** getter for person **by address**

We suggests the following class:

```
class PersonPool
{
public:
    void add_person(const Person& p)   { m_persons.insert(p.m_address, p); }
    bool person_exists(string address) { return m_persons.has_key(address);     }
    Person& get_person(string address) { return m_persons[address];             }
    void remove_person(string address) { m_persons.erase(address);              }

private:
    map<String,Person> m_persons;  ///> key: person address; value: Person's instance
};
```

### Useage Example

say I have this block of code:

1. PersonPool p_pool;
2. Person p1;
3. p1.m_address = "x";
4. p_pool.add_person(p1);
5. Person& p2 = p_pool.get_person("x");
6. p2.m_address = "y";
7. p_pool.get_person("y");

### Problem

line 6 in the example modifies the address of `Person`.
When I want to get a `Person` based on the new address ("y"), `PersonPool` will be unable to return this `Person`. 
 It does not "know" that the address was modified and still keep the old address, "x", as the key for that Person instance.

### Suggestions for `PersonPool` enhancement:

1. the key of the map should not be the address.
   **problems:**

   - what will be the right key? bear in mind that we need **fast** access by address.
   - what if the new key that we choose is also modified by `Person`'s users (even m_name may be modified)
2. add function to `PersonPool`:
   void update_person(string old_address, string new_address)
   **problems:**

   - Ugly. Users should **not** be bothered with my bad design.
   - what if user don't use this method
3. Provide const getter only. any modification to *Person*, stored in `PersonPool`, must be done using *new* function to be provided by `PersonPool` 
   **problems:**

   - breaks the class requirement. we need non-const getter
   - even if we give up on that requirement, that means the we have to duplicate `Person` interface in `PersonPool`. we certainly don't want to do that.

### Question:

Can you think of a better `PersonPool` implementation. Is it possible to tweak my suggestion and get rid of the problem.

***Thanks for your time!***

Comment: why 3 votes to close this question as "off topic"?

Comment: have no idea... is it that bad? by the way, how do you see those votes? first time I hear about it...

Comment: look at `close` link under your question tags

Comment: The description seems to imply that address will be a unique key, is this really a valid assumption?  Seems more likely that name+address would be unique.

Comment: even if all Person attributes are unique (let's assume they are), none of the attributes must remain constant through out the life of Person instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really tell if this is an academic exercise or not.  Regardless, it's difficult to say up with any certainty what specific storage implementation is going to give you the best performance.  This will depend on a number of factors, including (but not limited to):

- Size of your data set (how many people)
- Content of your data set (format and size of the strings)
- Efficiency of the specific library you are using
- Typical usage (optimize for lookup vs update)

The approach I would take is to design the class interface to meet all usage requirements, build some simple performance tests, and start comparing the relative performance of different storage implementations.  Begin with the simplest implementations, moving on to more complex optimizations if needed (avoid premature optimization!).

This is the benefit of encapsulation:  You are free to change your internal implementation details without affecting the users of the interface.

Also, using address as a unique key doesn't seem like it would work.  If you are actually modeling real-world data, wouldn't it be possible for more than one person to have the same address (or name, or phone number)?  I would probably use an internal function to encapsulate the details of the unique key as well.

Some suggestions for the class interface:

```
// use typedefs to make changes easier
typedef string KEY_TYPE;
typedef map<KEY_TYPE, Person> PERSON_POOL;
typedef vector<Person> PERSONS;

class PersonPool
{
public:
    void add_person(const Person& p);
    void update_person(const Person& p);
    Person get_person(string name, string address);
    void remove_person(string name, string address);
    bool person_exists(string name, string address);

    // find zero or more persons
    PERSONS get_persons_by_name(string name);
    PERSONS get_persons_by_address(string address);
    PERSONS get_persons_by_number(string number);

private:
    KEY_TYPE get_key(string name, string address);
    KEY_TYPE get_key(const Person &p);
    PERSON_POOL m_persons;
};
```

Example implementation:

```
void Person::add_person(const Person& p)
{
    m_persons.insert(get_key(p), p);
}

Person Person::get_person(const Person& p)
{
    PERSON_POOL::iterator i = find(m_persons.begin(), m_persons.end(), get_key(p));
    if (i != m_persons.end())
        return i->second;
    throw "person not found";
}
```

Anyway, good luck with your project.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. By the way, it is not an academic exercise but real life problem I encountered several time in our code. The Person example is just artificial to make things simpler. I really am working with storage class that their members are not constant but we need fast access based on some member.

Comment: IMHO empirical testing via specific performance tests is the quickest path to an optimal solution.  I not sure why the fact that members can change should be a problem though?  The key can change, as long as it's done through the storage interface.

Answer (score 0):

Using std::map with address as the key isn't a good idea. How about using a vector as so:

```
class Person
{
public:
    string m_name;
    string m_address;
    string m_phone_number;
    bool operator == (const Person& other)
    {
        return m_address == other.m_address;
    }
};

class PersonPool
{
public:
    void add_person(const Person& p)   { m_persons.push_back(p); }
    bool person_exists(string address) { return (getPerson(address) != m_persons.end());     }
    Person& get_person(string address) { return (*getPerson(address)); }
    void remove_person(string address) { m_persons.erase(getPerson(address)); }

private:
    vector<Person> m_persons; 
    vector<Person>::iterator getPerson(string address)
    {
        return find(m_persons.begin(), m_persons.end(), address);
    }
};
```

Comment: What is get_person() time complexity in your implementation? not as fast as map.

Comment: stl::find is linear complexity

Comment: kinda breaks the fast access requirement. we may keep the map. upon get request, if we have the key and it matches the real address we may return it. if not, we can scan the map and sync its key with the real address in Person instances